# Java Swing: JScrollPane containing JTextArea filled with text gets very small when moved to 2nd monitor

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have a Java Swing GUI that consists of some JScrollPanes containing JTextAreas that get filled with data so that the scrollbars appear.  Once the scrollbars appear, when I move the window to my second monitor, the JScrollPane gets very small so that I can no longer see the text it contains.

Example:

Here is the window on my main monitor with the JScrollPane filled with text:
[image]

Here is the window after I filled it with text and moved it to the second monitor:
[image]

Here is a small example program that demonstrates the problem:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    public Main() {
        Test theGui = new Test();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(true);
        add(theGui);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Main();
            }
        });
    }
}

class Test extends JPanel {
    private static final int PADDING = 3;
    private JLabel label;
    private JTextArea textarea;
    private JScrollPane scrollpane;
    private GridBagConstraints gbc;

    public Test() {
        super(new GridBagLayout());
        label = new JLabel("Fill this text box with text so the scrollbars appear, then move the window to 2nd monitor:");
        textarea = new JTextArea(10, 40);
        scrollpane = new JScrollPane(textarea);

        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(PADDING, PADDING, PADDING, PADDING);
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        gbc.gridwidth = 4;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        add(label, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        add(scrollpane, gbc);

    }
}
```

Note that the JScrollPane only gets very small when moving to the other monitor when it is filled with text.  If there is no text in it, it seems to stay the right size.

My question is, how can I prevent the JScrollPane from getting very small when I move the window to my second monitor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GridBagLayout` will revert to the components `minimumSize` property when the available space for the component is less then the components `preferredSize`.

You can override this by using the `GridBagConstraints`, `weightx`/`weighty` properties, for example.

```
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 1;
gbc.weightx = 1;
gbc.weighty = 1;
add(scrollpane, gbc);
```